# What is the IUPAC name of the following compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the *IUPAC name* of this molecule with a dihalide alkyl chain?

[image: dibromo-substituted compound]

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! We ask that you share some of your work in solving your homework problems, so we can best help you learn.

Comment: You also might want to consider reading our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3120/7951).

Comment: Related: [IUPAC Naming: 2-phenyloctane or 2-octanylbenzene](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19229/7951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When listing *preferred IUPAC names*, the ring prioritized over the chain (making it a substituent), especially when the chain is **shorter** than the ring.

First we label the carbon at the end of the chain as '1' and continue across the chain. The bromines are at positions 2 & 3, and it is a 5 carbon chain. So, we label it as pentyl chain and it therefore follows the IUPAC name is

(2,3-dibromopentyl)benzene

Comment: When i tried to the nomenclature, i was getting the iupac name as 2,3-dibromo-1-phenylpentane. This is because i think that the benzene ring should be considered a substituent as it contains the functional group (halides).

Comment: What about 2,3-dibromo-1-phenylpentane???

Comment: @sankalprajabhoj 2,3-dibromo-1-phenylpentane is a correct systematic name in accordance with current IUPAC recommendations; however, it is not the _preferred_ IUPAC name.